# Adding helm hooks to RBAC resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to create a `post-install,post-upgrade` `helm` hook (a `Job` to be more precise).

This will need the following RBAC resources (I have already added the corresponding helm-hook annotations)

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-role"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded,hook-failed
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["get"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-rolebinding"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded,hook-failed
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
    name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-sa"
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-role"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-sa"
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install,pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded,hook-failed
```

In my corresponding `Job` spec:

```
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": post-install,post-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation

...
serviceAccountName: "{{ .Release.Name }}-post-install-sa"
```

I though that by adding `pre-` to the RBAC resources, I would make sure these were created **before** the actual `Job` which is a `post-` thing.

By also setting the `hook-delete-policy` to `before-hook-creation,hook-succeeded,hook-failed`, these would also be deleted in all cases (whether the Job failed or succeeded) to avoid having them lying around for security considerations.

However the `Job` creation errors out as unable to find the `ServiceAccount`

```
error looking up service account elastic/elastic-stack-post-install-sa: serviceaccount "elastic-stack-post-install-sa" not found
```

Why is that?

Comment: Did the solution of PGS help you?

Comment: Haven't had the time to test it out yet. will do and get back by posting here; sounds promising

Comment: Do you have any progress?

Comment: Hi, did you find the reason for this behavior? by adding post-upgrade to the rbac it works!!
Even I'm facing the same issue. For post-upgrade job the the rbac is not accessible though it was created during pre-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hook weight to ensure a deterministic order.Helm loads the hook with the lowest weight first (negative to positive)

```
"helm.sh/hook-weight": "0"
```

Example:
Service account creation with lowest weight.

Answer (score 0):

As PGS suggested, "**helm.sh/hook-weight**" annotation is the solution here.

Important Notes:

1. Hook weights can be positive, zero or negative numbers but must be represented as **strings**.
   *Example:* **"helm.sh/hook-weight": "-5"** *(Note: -5 within double quotes)*
2. When Helm starts the execution cycle of hooks of a particular Kind it will sort those hooks in ascending order.

**Hook weights ensure below:**

1. Execute in the right weight sequence *(negative to positive in ascending order)*
2. Block each other *(Important for your scenario)*
3. All block main K8s resource from starting